# distinct and startswith in the same linq query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

I need to write the following SQL query in LINQ for an ASP.net MVC application:

`select distinct(COST_CENTER) from FDCostCenterRequest where COST_CENTER like '10%'`

The definition of COST_CENTER column in FDCostCenterRequest is following:

`public string COST_CENTER { get; set; }`

I have wrote it in the following manner:

```
IEnumerable<FDCostCenterRequest> suggestions = 
    from cc in db.FDCostCenterRequests.Where(cc => 
    cc.COST_CENTER.StartsWith(searchString)).ToList() select cc;

var selected = from costList in suggestions select costList.COST_CENTER.Distinct();

List<string> dropDownInfos = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in selected)
{
    dropDownInfos.Add(item.ToString());
}
```

But when I try to view the dropDownInfos content I get `System.Linq.Enumerable+<DistinctIterator>d__81`1[System.Char]` for each and every record. What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Which property are you adding to dropdowninfos?

Answer (score 2):

```
var yourItems = db.FDCostCenterRequests.Where(cc => cc.COST_CENTER.StartsWith(searchString)).Select(o=>o.COST_CENTER).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting the distinct cost centers from each of your centers, you're transforming each of your centers into the set of distinct characters that make up the cost center.

You could parenthesize the query differently, but it's easier if you just don't switch betweeen query and method syntax so much:

```
var query = db.FDCostCenterRequests
    .Where(cc => cc.COST_CENTER.StartsWith(searchString))
    .Select(cc => cc.COST_CENTER)
    .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `string` implements IEnumerable, your `Distinct` is operating on that. Wrap the remainder of the query in parentheses so that `Distinct` operates on the query.

```
var selected = (from costList in suggestions
                 select costList.COST_CENTER).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it by the following:

```
var suggestions = from cc in db.FDCostCenterRequests.Where(cc => cc.COST_CENTER.StartsWith(searchString)).GroupBy(x=>x.COST_CENTER).Select(g=>g.Key)
                          select cc;
```

I know it is a bit round about, but still thanks for your answers.